# How to validate shipping address per product by city and restrict user?

Tags: validation, restrictions, magento-1.9.1

I am using Magento 1.9. I want to create product and make available in only specific cities. And also I want to restrict users on checkout when they select product to ship in the city where the product is not available.

I am a beginner at Magento and don't know how to achieve this.

What I have in mind so far is, it will be good to create an attribute named `'city'`, make it `multiselect` and add cities as it's options. So now I can create product and assign multiple cities to it. and can be seen at the `'Additional Information tab'` on frontend product's page.

But now I want to restrict user if he select orders product available in "New York" and he submitted shipping address with any other city. This should restrict the further process and display message.

In short, I want to restrict user on checkout and display message. `"The product is not available in the specified address/city/location etc"`

Comment: @AadilKeshwani: please see my edit that follows yours. Inline preformatting is ideal for code, classnames, console i/o and, perhaps, some on-screen UI items. It is not a general highlighter, so Magento and other brand names can be written just using the rules for proper nouns (initial cap). Thanks.